# Shiny Equation in SelectInput options

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I am building an application based on simulated data.
I want to specify the choice of the distribution of the error as an input for example: N(0, \sigma^2_\epsilon).
The problem is that it works (I have equations written) when I load the page for the first time, but once I change the input, it becomes 'code' and not formula anymore.
Is there any way to have it displaying formulas all the time?

Here is my code:

```
 wellPanel(style = "background-color: #F0F8FF;", ##ffffff   #FFECE9 # nice ~ red  #F5FFEA # nice ~ red 
               withMathJax(),
               selectInput("type", label = h5("Distribution of the errors (\\( \\epsilon \\))"), 
                           choices = list(
                                       "Gaussian N(\\( 0, \\sigma^2_\\epsilon \\))" = "gaussian", 
                                       "Student(df = n-1)" = "student", 
                                       "Laplace(\\( 0, \\sigma^2_\\epsilon \\))" = "laplace"),
                           selected = "gaussian")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use **katex** instead of MathJax. See an example here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1506#issuecomment-403451304